# Compile zip with gradle including libraries implemented by a sibling subproject

Tags: java, gradle, aws-lambda

I have a java project made by some sibling modules. One of these modules is a library and I'm applying `java-library` plugin on it. All the other modules depend on it.

What I need to do is to automate the creation of a zip for each module, containing all the classes and all the dependencies needed for it to work (I'm deploying the zip as aws-lambda functions).

So far this is what I have achieved, but the resulting zip only contains module's classes. I thought that the problem might be the type of dependency I'm using (implementation) and I tried [switching to the default one](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) but gradle doesn't even success in building.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    from compileJava
    from processResources
    from configurations.runtime
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':utils')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Comment: "I have a java project made by some sibling modules" <- Do you mean you have a multi-project build? Or is the Java project _created_ by these modules? I assume the former, but would like to clarify.

Comment: Hmmm...you might be running into an ordering issue here. Try putting the task definitions _after_ the `dependencies {}` block.

Comment: @PeterLedbrook the former

Comment: @PeterLedbrook I'm actually calling the task manually

Comment: Still, I think you have a build script ordering issue. I suspect that `configurations.runtime` is empty when you use it, since it's not populated until the `dependencies {}` section. Please try the change and let me know if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @PeterLedbrook ok thank you, I'll let you know asap! 

Comment: BTW, I think you should be using `runtimeClasspath` rather than `runtime`. I'll try to find out as I struggle to understand the difference between `runtimeClasspath` and `runtimeElements` as described in the Java Library Plugin chapter: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html

Comment: @PeterLedbrook it looks like nothing changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some testing, I think I have the answer.

First: the order you declared the task and the dependencies is fine! It's OK to use a configuration before it's populated. I only say this because I indicated in my comments that it might be an issue.

Second, the issue here is the use of `configurations.runtime`. This does not extend `implementation` and `api`, so those dependencies are not included. `runtime` has been superseded by `runtimeOnly`, which hopefully makes the behaviour clear.

The following task definition should work:

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    from compileJava
    from processResources
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
}
```